# Not getting success response in ajax call, every time going to error function

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets

I am trying to get json data from servlet, from back-end I am getting proper response but every time call is going to error block of ajax call.
Here is My JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function()

{
    $("#submit").on("click", function()
    {

        userId = $("#userNameTxt").val();
        seqAns = $("#seqAnsTxt").val();
        seqQues = $("#seqQues").val();
        command = $("#_CMD").val()
        alert(command);
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            dataType : "json",
            url : "/Inventory/InvController",
            data : {_CMD : command, uid : userId, ques : seqQues, ans : seqAns},
            success : function(retVal)
            {
                alert("success");
                var test = $.parseJSON(retVal);
                if(true)
                {
                    $("#resetPwd").show();
                }
            },
            error: function(error)
            {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here is My Servlet Code:

```
boolean isSuccess = logHelper.performForgotPwdValidation(agentDetails);

PrintWriter out = null;

    JsonObject jsonObj = new JsonObject();
    try 
    {
        jsonObj.addProperty("isValid", isSuccess);

        response.setContentType( "application/json" );

        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        out = response.getWriter();
        out.write(jsonObj.toString());
        out.flush();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if( null != out )
        {
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

While running every time it is going to the error function of the ajax call.

please help if I am doing anything wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of alert("error") why don't you console.log(error) and add this to your question?

Comment: previously I also used console.log(error). In conse I am getting this message: Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "
↵<!DOCTYPE html>
↵
↵<html>
↵<head>
↵<meta http-eq…=no, titlebar=no", true);
↵ }
↵</script>
↵</html>", status: 200, statusText: "OK"} @Jake

Comment: So a status code of 200 suggests the actual posting works. Please see below answer and try wrapping your data, as it's now a plain JS object, not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Your data type is JSON, but your data is just a JavaScript object. Use JSON.stringify() around the data so it's valid JSON data. (Change to JSON.stringify({_CMD : command, uid : userId, ques : seqQues, ans : seqAns}) )

Comment: Still its not working...is there any issue in my servlet code?@JakeRowsell

Comment: It might be worth adding Java or Servlet tags, as I have no idea about those.

Comment: After removing dataType : "json", from my JS code and changing response.setContentType( "application/json" ); to response.setContentType( "text/plain" ); I am able to redirect the call to success call back function. But it would be great if any body could let me know how to send the json data from servlet and retrieve the from JS.